# How should I split up my js-files to be easy to maintain?

Tags: javascript, include

How would I go about when trying to separate javascript in this manner:

**This is my issue:**
I have a huge js-file and in this file I have functions that is used for a products-filter. I want to use these "product-filter-functions" at several locations, but I don't want to include a huge js-file.

I would like something like:

```
huge.js          // merely everything that has something to do with products
productfilter.js // inclusion of productfilter-functions */
```

and when I only want to use product-filter function I obviosly include *productfilter.js* only.

***productfilter.js would have functions like these:***

```
function getSelectedGender() {    
...
}

function getSelectedColors() {
....
}

function getSelectedBrandId() {
....
}
```

If I have a function with the same name in both huge.js and productfilter.js I wouldn't know which of these function would be triggered. (I tried that and it seemed kind of random)

I could of course write new functions (with the same type of functionality) depending on which part of the site I am, but I think that would be poor design and very hard to maintain.

I'm looking for pointers here..

Comment: Have a look at browserify: http://browserify.org/

Comment: Sounds like you want name spacing.

Comment: when building sites, i find loading two scripts site-wide works best. one is the stuff that every page needs (jq,bs,etc). the 2nd one varies according to the needs of the section it's loaded from (validators, media galleries, etc). sometimes the 2nd scripts loads more using require, and sometimes it assembled by a build process. if a single page in a section needs more, I load a 3rd script just for that page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try namespacing the JS so that you can keep your function names, e.g.:

```
huge.functionName()
product.functionName()
```

instead of

```
functionName()
functionName()
```

Comment: I think this is what I need. I would have to read up on how to implement namespacing in js though. Thanks!

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld: Namespacing is basically wrapping all your methods in a named object literal. Here's [an easy way](http://blog.arc90.com/2008/06/06/an-easy-way-to-implement-namespaces-in-javascript/) to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a fan of [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) for developing modules in a tidy manner with well-established dependencies. During [building/optimizing](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) the final distribution JS file (if chosen), *only the required/requested modules will be included.* So code can focus on dependencies and logical grouping, while the build tool includes the relevant modules. Larger or external modules (eg. jQuery) can also be kept external and sourced via manually script includes or loaded via a separate asynchronous "AMD" fetch.

However, even *without* RequireJS/AMD, modules can be used to keep JavaScript code tidy in separate namespaces. I refer to the ["UMD" patterns](https://github.com/umdjs/umd), adapted to current need. Take this "AMD Web Global" pattern with a jQuery dependency, for instance:

```
(function (root, factory) {
    // The if-branch can be eliminated if /never/ using RequireJS/AMD,
    // but leaving it in keeps this pattern compatible with such loaders.
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(['jQuery'], function (jQuery) {
            return (root.foo = factory(jQuery));
        });
    } else {
        root.foo = factory(root.jQuery);
    }
}(this, function ($) {
    function bar() {    
        // ...
    }
    return {
        bar: bar
    };
}));
```

Later on the created "namespace" can be used:

```
foo.bar()
```

This pattern works with/without AMD (eg. RequireJS) and will also work after combining, if such is chosen. If tool-based combining is not done, then the standard multiple script includes can be used to load the dependencies (a downside is that dependency order must be handled manually).

An added benefit of using such module patterns is it is trivial to change to a context-correct factory builder:

```
// In the module, exported as window.OptionManager using the above pattern
}(this, function ($) {
    function OptionManager (form) {
        this.getSelectedGender = function () {
            return $(form).find(".gender").val();
        };
    }
    return OptionManager;
}));
```

And usage:

```
var options = new OptionManager($("#optionForm"));
options.getSelectedGender();
```

With the clean distinction of code it is trivial to later combine the different modules, maintaining dependencies, as deemed appropriate - separate files, single monolithic file, several combined files - while the code-base is kept maintainable.

Comment: I think this is a great answer, but in my specific case I think namespaces is the way to go (I might be wrong. Time will tell). But I'l bookmark this page (yes, really!), so I could go back here for future projects